# I/O operation on closed file. with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I`ve just started a tutorial and I got stuck :(

This is the code

```
from io import BytesIO
import pandas
table1 = BytesIO(resp1.content)
pandas.read_excel(table1)
```

( I am using Jupyter notebook anaconda)
If I put this, It works
After that, I just write

```
pandas.read_excel(table1)
```

and there is an error `"I/O operation on closed file"`

So i re-write all again, it works. 
I dont know what happen, I assume Pandas expired?

What I want is define "`pandas.read_excel(table1)` " as data, so I can copy the result to my local computer.`/  data = pandas.read_excel(table1) /`

Please Help me... [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDeLm.png)

Comment: You are saying it works the first time you call it but not the second? Generally, you wouldn't read it twice, but you could `table1.seek(0)` and use the i/o buffer again.

Answer (score 0):

```
pandas.read_excel(table1)
```

The above command is not correct.
You need to put a dataframe at the beginning to read the Excel to, e.g.:

```
df=pandas.read_excel(table1)
```